# Can _Generic match on string of type?

Tags: c, generics

Example use-case, do a thing for all types that contain the string "int". More precise, have a struct `Point` in different versions as `Point__alloca` or `Point__boehm`, and then a macro `new` that switches on that name. Hm, maybe macro stringification could do that?

Comment: IRC channel says no. :) I can stringify the macro argument but not inspect it during compile-time.

Comment: What does is mean "all types that contain the string 'int'" ? What are those diffenet versions of `Point`? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard C supports only very limited introspection (examination of the program by itself) and nothing that would discern whether a type name contained particular characters or any ability to enumerate “all types” at all, let alone all types matching a criterion. In short, there is no support for the feature you request.